# SharePoint limits when moving and copying files and folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, limitations

Inside this documentation @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#moving-and-copying-across-sites it mentioned the following:-

[image]

so is it saying that each of the moved files cannot have their individual size greater than 100 GB? or it is talking about the total size of all the files and folders that can be moved in one run?

Comment: The limit is 100 GB total file size of all files and folders that can be moved or copied in a single operation. The individual file size limits are 2 GB limit for OneNote files and 15 GB limit for cross-geo copy or move.

Comment: @MartinIszac thanks